# grub2 using wrong /boot partition

Tags: ubuntu, partition, grub2, uefi

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB. I did everything the same way I'd done when upgrading from 14 to 16, and 16 to 17, and it worked every time until now. I selected "erase ubuntu 17 and install ubuntu 18" while running 18 from a USB image. Here is my issue: Grub2 loads, but seems to be using the wrong config file in the wrong partition. In order to run ubuntu I have to set the root dir to `/dev/sda8` and set the proper `linux` and `initrd` files which live in `/dev/sda8/boot`(this is also where the `grub.cfg` file I want to use lives).  I can see there is a `grub.cfg` file on `dev/sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` that just points to `/dev/sda5` which is the BIOS partition. My question is, how can I get grub to use the config file I have updated from ubuntu (the one at `/dev/sda8/boot`)? I am worried that if I change the one on `/dev/sda1`, I will seriously break something, but if not, would it suffice to use the contents of the cfg file on `sda8`?

Here is the terminal output of `fdisk -l` for reference:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    468991    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     468992 816990982 816521991 389.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  816992256 818726911   1734656   847M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  818726912 818728959      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda6  935913472 939819007   3905536   1.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda7  942651392 976773119  34121728  16.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8  818728960 935913471 117184512  55.9G Linux filesystem
```

The file `/dev/sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` has the following contents, note that `(hd0,5)` is the BIOS partition:

```
search.fs_uuid 7e076866-97b4-4d3c-b864-491137212645 root hd0,gpt5
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. If your system is EFI (as it seems to be), why do you need a second grub.cfg on /dev/sda8? Why can't you just configure the one on /dev/sda1 to boot everything? What else are you booting on the machine, besides Ubuntu?

Comment: I did not put the `grub.cfg` on `/dev/sda8`, the command `sudo update-grub2` did. Also, part of my question was whether I could just put the contents of the config file on `dev/sda8` into the one in the EFI partition without breaking anything. I am dual booting Windows 10. Perhaps I can tell `config-grub2` to update the file on `sda1`?

Comment: Ok. Was the live USB definitely created and booted in EFI mode, not 'legacy BIOS' mode? I believe 'update-grub2' needs to be run from a system in the same boot mode as the one it is trying to update.

Comment: Of this I am uncertain. It was made on windows with rufus. I assume I would have to go into the firmware to check what mode it booted in? or could I possibly infer this from the config file on `sda8?`

Comment: This page might help you determine if the live USB is booting in EFI or legacy mode: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162564/how-can-i-tell-if-my-system-was-booted-as-efi-uefi-or-bios

Comment: Looks like EFI judging by the terminal output. Interestingly enough, the `grub.cfg` file on my EFI partition (`/dev/sda1`) points to the BIOS partition (`/dev/sda5`), though...Adding the (very short) `grub.cfg` file contents to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79164/discussion-between-time4tea-and-thisguycanteven).

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'BIOS partition'? Are you trying to boot different OSes in EFI and 'legacy BIOS' mode?

Answer (score 7):

For those who find this question in the future, and use **cloud-init** on their server (either dedicated servers e.g. via MAAS, or virtual servers (VPS's) via any virtualisation software or "cloud" providers), there's a very easy fix.

## How I ran into this issue

I migrated the rootfs on one of my VMs from it's original root partition, to a new disk - and I found that `update-grub` would keep using the PARTUUID of the original rootfs. First I assumed it was just an issue related to running it within a chroot, so I manually corrected the UUIDs in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and rebooted.

After booting into the new rootfs partition, I ran `update-grub`, hoping that running it from the real system running on the new disk, it would now use the correct UUIDs - unfortunately not.

I searched the internet and came to this StackExchange question, one answer advised checking `/boot/efi` for any potential extra config files that might be contributing. Sure enough, I found `/boot/efi/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which appeared to contain a hard coded FS UUID:

```
root@host ~ # cat /boot/efi/boot/grub/grub.cfg
# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
search.fs_uuid 897a358a-acba-4b07-867c-33d1ca3b28dc root hd0,gpt1
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

I corrected the `fs_uuid`, but this still didn't completely fix `update-grub` setting the wrong PARTUUID in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

However, I eventually noticed a suspicious config file in the logs of the `update-grub` command:

```
root@host ~ # update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/40-force-partuuid.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-71-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-71-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-24-generic
done
```

## The final fix for the issue

Hm... `Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub.d/40-force-partuuid.cfg'` - force partuuid? Looked to be the culprit.

```
root@host ~ # cat /etc/default/grub.d/40-force-partuuid.cfg
GRUB_FORCE_PARTUUID=897a358a-acba-4b07-867c-33d1ca3b28dc
```

Sure enough, it contained the partition UUID that kept being set in the GRUB config, despite being incorrect.

After changing `GRUB_FORCE_PARTUUID` to be the PARTUUID of my rootfs partition, and re-running `update-grub`, it finally used the correct PARTUUID in the grub.cfg :)

## Summary

To fix this issue on systems which use `cloud-init`, first you'll need to note down both the filesystem UUID (`UUID=`) and the partition UUID (`PARTUUID=`) for your root filesystem (and/or possibly your boot partition if you have a separate one) from the `blkid` command:

```
root@host ~ # blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="wcrpSm-QCZu-VN3A-I503-sQqQ-5xfw-76r5bd" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="bec389fc-4274-5245-babb-7d90674f1662"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL_FATBOOT="UEFI" LABEL="UEFI" UUID="072E-C819" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="78730ead-03d3-e14d-b4fe-ee0abf4f0ad5"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="6cea6786-510a-4fba-871b-7811b63b3453" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="530c353b-0be8-e34e-affb-bd5c2332abc7"
```

In my case, `/dev/sdb3` is both the rootfs and boot partition.

So now, open up `/boot/efi/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with the editor of your choice (e.g. `nano` or `vim`), and replace the UUID part of `fs_uuid XXXX-XXXX` with your filesystem UUID, for example, in my case, it is `6cea6786-510a-4fba-871b-7811b63b3453`

Next, open up `/etc/default/grub.d/40-force-partuuid.cfg` and replace the UUID value of `GRUB_FORCE_PARTUUID=` with your PARTITION UUID (PARTUUID), which in my case is `530c353b-0be8-e34e-affb-bd5c2332abc7`.

Finally, run `update-grub` - and then check `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and confirm that it now uses the correct FS UUID + PARTUUID.

You should now be able to update your GRUB config, and reboot in peace, without getting stuck in an initramfs due to invalid UUIDs :)

Comment: OMG thank you. Sooooo many rabbitholes. You win the Internet today.

Comment: Had this exact same problem with an Ubuntu 20.04 VM created via Hyper-V's Quick Create option, same `40-force-partuuid.cfg`. Ran `sudo blkid` and was able to fix this right up, thank you.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's why even the PARTUUID in the grub is correct, mine still fail. I didn't check the fs_uuid part.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, I'm confused about what the 'BIOS boot' partition is for, and why you have several different `grub.cfg` files spread across different partitions. I think all you should need is one `grub.cfg` file, from which should be able to boot up both Linux and Windows.

Another thing is to make absolutely sure that the live USB you are updating from was created and booted in EFI mode, *not* legacy BIOS boot mode. An easy way to check this is to boot up from the USB and check to see if the file /sys/firmware/efi exists. If it doesn't, then it wasn't booted in EFI mode.

I have a fairly similar dual-boot system with Windows/Linux. I have checked it and there is only one `grub.cfg` file, on the Linux system root partition in the /boot/grub folder. The EFI system partition is being mounted at /boot/efi during boot.

With regards to your question about modifying the `grub.cfg` on the EFI partition: there shouldn't be any harm in doing that. In fact, if you do need multiple `grub.cfg` files for some reason, it would probably be best to maintain the files yourself anyway (rather than hoping the auto update tool will handle it correctly). I would back-up the auto-created file first, and you can also test out boot commands on the grub command line, before modifying the file. The worst that would likely happen if you do mess something up is that you'll get dumped into a GRUB command prompt, where you'll have to enter the boot commands manually. If you don't know how to do that, then you might have to boot via a live USB and fix/restore the file.

The other thing is though, that if you do make changes to `grub.cfg` manually, they might get overwritten the next time GRUB does an auto-update (in that case, I would probably disable the `update-grub command` in your linux distribution).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Time4Tea for helping me along. As it turns out, there was a VERY VERY SIMPLE fix for this. The `grub.cfg` file I posted earlier that lived at `(hd0,1)/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` aka `/dev/sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` just needed to have the prefix changed from `(hd0,gpt5)` to `(hd0,8)`, which is where the `grub.cfg` file that I created with `sudo update-grub2` was located. I overwrote it with nano and saved it by mounting `/dev/sda1/` from ubuntu (after manually using grub terminal to boot into ubuntu). Below is the new file with the one small change:

```
search.fs_uuid 7e076866-97b4-4d3c-b864-491137212645 root hd0,gpt5
set prefix=(hd0,8)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Answer (score 1):

I never had a problem cloning disks until ubuntu 20.04. Then
I would clone and on boot grub would complain about not finding 'disk c871cf8d21f6a1ce' or some such. then I worked out the fix.

SOURCE DISK

My source disk is laid out like:

## fdisk -l /dev/sda

Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048   1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2   1026048  19900415  18874368     9G Linux swap
/dev/sda3  19900416 488397133 468496718 223.4G Linux filesystem

The fs_uuid of the source disk is, of course:

## grub-probe -t fs_uuid -d /dev/sda1

c871cf8d21f6a1ce

In the /boot directory there is

## find /BACKUP/blesbok-daily/boot/efi/ | grep grub.cfg

/BACKUP/blesbok-daily/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg

## cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grug.cfg

search.fs_uuid c871cf8d21f6a1ce root hd0,gpt3
set prefix=($root)'/ROOT/blesbok@/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

NOTE -->Your system ~may~ have other 'grub.cfg' under other /boot/efi. You
will have to change all of them as directed, below. <-- NOTE

The relevent parts of '/boot/grub/grub.cfg' are:
...
set root='cryptouuid/c03cff716cab4e93843db1f16b8ba5a8'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/c03cff716cab4e93843db1f16b8ba5a8'  c871cf8d21f6a1ce
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c871cf8d21f6a1ce
...
set root='hd1,gpt3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3
...

There are, of course, many references to 'hd1,gpt3' and 'c871cf8d21f6a1ce' in '/etc/default/grub.cfg'

CLONE DISK

Say I have a different partition scheme for the clone as:

## fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Device             Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1         2048     1026047    1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sdc2      1024000  1115686911 1048576000   500G 83 Linux

and

## grub-probe -t fs_uuid -d /dev/sdc1

927ccf30-88b7

I mount all partitions and clone per usual with 'rsync'. I chroot with:

```
cd /mnt ; mkdir dev sys proc run ; cd /                                                                                                  
mount --bind /run /mnt/run                                                                                                               
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev                                                                                                               
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys                                                                                                               
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc                                                                                                             
chroot /mnt/
```

PROBLEM: We have to install grub on the clone but 'update-grub' appears to read
from the disk that booted the computer to make the clone (may not be the source disk) and make a grub.cfg that will not boot the clone disk. In chroot we have to install grub (for either UEFI or BIOS), put back the original source grub.cfg files from source to  clone and edit, putting in the clone's 'gptX' and fs_uuid.

FOR EFI SYSTEMS (in chroot)
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64 ; grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=arch_grub --recheck --debug ; efibootmgr -c --disk /dev/sdc --part 1

```
(NOTE that the clone in my example is 'sdc'. I also find that I sometimes have
 to run this TWICE to properly install grub)
```

FOR BIOS SYSTEMS (in chroot)
grub-install /dev/sdX

IN EITHER SYSTEM - the magic

If you or your install script ran 'uodate-grub' or 'grub-mkconfig' any 'grub.cfg' reflect the source disk. GET RID OF THEM! Replace them AGAIN with those from the source as they reflect the boot environment of the source disk. You now have to edit those files to refer to the clone disk.

In all 'grub.cfg' under /boot

1. Replace 'c871cf8d21f6a1ce' (fs_uuid of the source disk) with '927ccf30-88b7' (fs_uuid of the clone disk)
2. replace 'gpt3' with 'gpt2' since the root partition of the clone disk is 'sdc2' and the root of the source was /dev/sda3,

   IMPORTANT: also replace any instance of 'hdX' with 'hd0'

   /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grug.cfg
   search.fs_uuid 927ccf30-88b7 root hd0,gpt2
   set prefix=($root)'/ROOT/blesbok@/boot/grub'
   configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

   /boot/grub/grub.cfg'
   ...
   set root='cryptouuid/c03cff716cab4e93843db1f16b8ba5a8'
   if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/c03cff716cab4e93843db1f16b8ba5a8'  927ccf30-88b7
   else
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 927ccf30-88b7
   ...
   set root='hd0,gpt2'
   if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt2
   ...

Please remember to replace ALL occurances of these in the entire
'/boot/grub/grub.cfg'

DO NOT RUN 'update-grub' IN CHROOT!!

That's it.

Remember to fix up fstab and any other files if you're using LUKS. 'umount'
everything and reboot. From then on running 'update-grub' will make the
correct grub.cfg files.

_*END*

Answer (score 0):

If you came here after a very long search trying to get Ubuntu cloud image working on Virt-manager, because you are getting the "GRUB_FORCE_PARTUUID attempting initrdless boot" error see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375589/what-are-the-different-versions-available-as-ubuntu-cloud-images

Commenting out this line in the file /etc/default/grub.d/40-force-partuuid.cfg (as mentioned above) along with moving the other two files seems to have worked after using `update-grub`.